# gcm sends me a push only when i am on wifi and cell network

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make a simple messaging app for a class project when I send a push for my server to gcm when the phone is on  WiFi it works fine when I use 3g (4g not tested) network it doesn't send the push at all

I tried on the post to gcm

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids'  => array( $reg_id ),
        'data'              => array( "message" => $message,"chat_id" => $chat_id ),
        'delay_while_idle'  => false,
        'time_to_live'      => 2019200

    ); 

'delay_while_idle'  => true, and no successes


<permission
android:name="in.ultraneo.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"   
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="in.ultraneo.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />



<receiver
            android:name=".MyC2dmReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="in.ultraneo.c2dm" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="in.ultraneo.c2dm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**receiver class**

```
 public class MyC2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static String KEY = "c2dmPref";
    private static String REGISTRATION_KEY = "registrationKey";
    private Context context;
    private String name,message,time,chat_id;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
    private NotificationManager manager;
    private  Bundle extras;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
            String registrationId = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
            handleRegistration(context, intent);

            if(registrationId!=null)
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(context,register.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.putExtra("regkey",registrationId);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {

            Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle!=null)
            {
                name = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                chat_id = intent.getStringExtra("chat_id");
                //time= get time();
            }
            SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("OURINFO",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String active = sp.getString("chaton","");

             boolean flag = isForeground(context,"in.ultraneo.c2dm");

                        if(flag)
                        {
                            if(active.compareTo("yes")==0) {
                                Message.Message(context, "active is true");
                                Intent i = new Intent("ONLINE");
                                i.putExtra("msg",message);
                                i.putExtra("chat_id_rec",chat_id);
                                i.putExtra("name",message);
                                context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i,null);
                            }
                            else
                                Message.Message(context,"active is false but onpause or other activity");
                        }
                         else
                        {
                            Message.Message(context,"app is off line");
                            sendNotification(message, intent.getStringExtra("message"), name);
                        }
        }

    }


    private void handleRegistration(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String registration = intent.getStringExtra("registration_id");
        if (intent.getStringExtra("error") != null) {

            Log.d("c2dm", "registration failed");
            String error = intent.getStringExtra("error");
            if(error == "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE");
            }else if(error == "ACCOUNT_MISSING"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "ACCOUNT_MISSING");
            }else if(error == "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "AUTHENTICATION_FAILED");
            }else if(error == "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "TOO_MANY_REGISTRATIONS");
            }else if(error == "INVALID_SENDER"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "INVALID_SENDER");
            }else if(error == "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR"){
                Log.d("c2dm", "PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR");
            }
        } else if (intent.getStringExtra("unregistered") != null) {

            Log.d("c2dm", "unregistered");
            Toast.makeText(context,"C2DM unregistered sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (registration != null) {

            Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString(REGISTRATION_KEY, registration);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Registration Id:"+registration,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new UltraFileaccess().Load_Data("REGKEY", registration, context);

        }
    }


    public boolean isForeground(Context context,String PackageName){
        // Get the Activity Manager
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        // Get a list of running tasks, we are only interested in the last one,
        // the top most so we give a 1 as parameter so we only get the topmost.
        List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > task = manager.getRunningTasks(1);

        // Get the info we need for comparison.
        ComponentName componentInfo = task.get(0).topActivity;

        // Check if it matches our package name.
        if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(PackageName)) return true;

        // If not then our app is not on the foreground.
        return false;
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg,String mobno,String name) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("mobno", mobno);
        args.putString("name", name);
        args.putString("msg", msg);
        Intent chat = new Intent(context, chatmsgbox.class);
        chat.putExtra("load",false);
        chat.putExtra("INFO", args);
        chat.putExtra("chat_id_notifi",chat_id);
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        notification.setContentTitle(name);
        notification.setContentText(msg);
        notification.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        notification.setTicker("New Message!");
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,1000,chat, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        manager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, notification.build());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you system settings or other applications settings, as "google settings". This is not your app code problem.

Answer (score 2):

You put all your logic about receiving and showing notification in `MyC2dmReceiver` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`. If you look at documentation of [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService(android.content.Intent)), especially description of method [onReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)), you'll notice that you have limited time and freedom for custom logic.

From documentation:

> When it runs on the main thread you should never perform long-running
>   operations in it (there is a timeout of 10 seconds that the system
>   allows before considering the receiver to be blocked and a candidate
>   to be killed). You cannot launch a popup dialog in your implementation
>   of onReceive().
>
> If this BroadcastReceiver was launched through a `<receiver>`tag, then
>   the object is no longer alive after returning from this function. This
>   means you should not perform any operations that return a result to
>   you asynchronously

What you probably want to do is remove all logic from your `MyC2dmReceiver` `BroadcastReceiver`, and put it into service.

Example:

```
public class MyC2dmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver { //note this is now WakefullBroadcastReceiver
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // This is the Intent to deliver to our service.
        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyC2dmService.class);

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        Log.i("MyC2dmService", "Starting service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }
}
```

And code for service (taken from [WakefulBroadcastReceiver documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html))

```
public class MyC2dmService extends IntentService {
    public MyC2dmService() {
        super("MyC2dmService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // At this point MyC2dmReceiver is still holding a wake lock
        // for us.  We can do whatever we need to here and then tell it that
        // it can release the wakelock.  


        //move your code from MyC2dmReceiver here


        //and finally release wake lock.
        MyC2dmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

Hint: [on this page](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html), you have full introduction how to implement GCM client, and since C2DM and GCM API are deprecated from Google, you should start using (if possible) [Google Play Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html).

Comment: tested your answer didn't work public class MyC2dmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MyC2dmService.class);

        Message.Message(context,"test");

        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        Log.i("MyC2dmService", "Starting service @");
        startWakefulService(context, service);

    }
}

Comment: is it at least same as it were before this major change? you're getting notifications on WiFi, but not when on mobile network?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the delay_while_idle so the message gets delivered at the moment you've send it. Double check the time_to_live value and set it to a normal amount of time (for example 5 or 6 weeks) if you set it to 1 hour, the message may get deleted while in the queue to be send to you're receivers

Comment: $fields = array(
   
        'delay_while_idle'  => false,
        'time_to_live'      => 2019200

    );

Comment: You'll need to remove 'delay_while_idle'

Answer (score -1):

tested Tomo answer didn't worked  only on wifi it sends me a message

public class MyC2dmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent service = new Intent(context, MyC2dmService.class);

    Message.Message(context,"test");

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    Log.i("MyC2dmService", "Starting service @");
    startWakefulService(context, service);

}
```

}